# Unix file matching logic

Tags: shell-script, scripting, file-comparison

I have a project requirement in which I need to read file1 from top to bottom and match column 2 of it with column 3 of file2. Both files are tab delimited.

If a record matches, I have to write full record from file 1 to new file3 and if it doesn't match, I have to write the same record into error file (file4). File1 and file2 contain 500-510 records. Need to start reading file1 from start and find the value of column 2 in column 3 of file2 (full scan from top to bottom if required).

file1

```
ZZA 01  LIST18
ZZY 02  LIST38
UTW 80  LIST100
OOP 11  LIST56
```

file2

```
A1  21138   99999   LIST18
W1  20223   99999   LIST44
Z9  20355   99999   LIST56
O9  21002   21154   LIST11
```

file3

```
ZZA 01  LIST18
OOP 11  LIST56
```

file4

```
ZZY 02  LIST38
UTW 80  LIST100
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds do-able, lets see an example of what you've tried so far, and what problems you've had ?

Comment: I am very new to Unix (2 days), know very basic Unix commands and this has to be done by today itself. I am still exploring the ways to do it. If I can get a help to do this time, it would be great. I will continue learning more as this project is gonna stay for a year

Comment: "getting help" != "doing it for you"

Comment: We can't help unless you [edit] your question and show i) a few lines from file 1, ii) a few lines from file2 and iii) the output you would expect from the example you give. Make sure that the examples cover all cases (both matches and non-matches) so we can understand. Hint: look up the commands `join`, `sort` and `comm`.

Comment: Added record example from real file

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to match column 3 of file1 with column 4 of file2, you could use `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '
  NR==FNR{ arr[$4]; next }
  { print > (($3 in arr) ? "file3" : "file4") }
' file2 file1
```

This reads file2 first and saves the fourth field in array `arr` as index.
Then read file1 and `print` each record. If the third field exists in the array, redirect the output to file3, otherwise to file4 .